# What is the quickest way to check if a file has changed?

Tags: node.js

Node.js has a method fs.watch() , which is used for watching for file changes. But the api is unstable. Using other fs methods which are stable, what is the quickest way to check if a file has changed ?

EDIT: I don't want to use external modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into:

```
fs.stat(path, [callback])
```

The documentation gives last modified date: 
http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/fs.html#fs.stat

ala:

```
if (curr.mtime - prev.mtime) {
    // file has been changed
}
```

edit: leaving here just in case others would like to use a wrapper.
Look here, this seems to be something that could be useful: It is a wrapper for fs.watch / fs.watchFile
https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar

Comment: Then what is the point of fs.watch() ? Is there some reason that fs.stat was not good enough that fs.watch was created ?

Comment: I don't want to use external modules.

Comment: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener , that bit says that they are instances of fs.stat which allow for event binding, but from the docs it suggests you will still have to compare the times, as noted in post, to determine if the file was actually modified, and not just accessed.

Comment: I don't understand your point. Isn't that what you said in your post ? Can you explain please ?

Comment: yes, my apologies - I was just trying to be more succinct in my response. But yes, I was just reiterating. Sorry bout' that.